# Triggers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to run the following code the last few weeks but one of the problems is the fact that onEdit(e) is a simple trigger which is why it cannot access other files because that would require authorization, which trigger would you recommend me to solve this problem?

Thanks!

```
function onEdit() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
var cell =  sheet.getActiveCell();

var row = cell.getRow();
var column = cell.getColumn();


if ( row ===1 && column ===4 && sheet.getName() ==="Hoja 1" ) {

  sendData();
  
  //sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("5");
}

function sendData() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1pxS9F9YEagzzRyTOqIDGVpDaCEiY_Z1DOYxq1QVzWGk");

  var source_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Hoja 1");
  var target_sheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Hoja 2");
  
  var range1 = source_sheet.getRange(1, 7, 6, 1).getValues();
  
  target_sheet.getRange(1,1,6,1).setValues(range1);
}

}
```

Comment: You can use an installable onEdit trigger.  Use a different name for the trigger function otherwise you could get two triggers.  You can install it manually through the editor or programattically.  I recommend that you learn how to take advantage of the event object

Comment: How would you add the trigger on the Code ?

Comment: Are you the only user?

Comment: No, that is why i need this code to automatically update  data from another file everytime an user edits certain range of cells

Comment: The I would install it programmattically so that every user has to authenticate it.